# Rectangles drawn in JavaScript canvas keep overlapping

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to create a simple GUI interface in JavaScript by painting a bunch of rectangles using fillRect and strokeRect on a context of a canvas. To figure out the sizes of the rectangles I have an expression which takes the space available in the browser window and calculates coordinates for every rectangle. 
Weirdly, even though the coordinates don't intersect (I've checked by outputting the coordinate values) - the rectangles do. 
Here's the code:

```
var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var w; 
var h;
var sectionH;
var sectionW;
var sectionX;
var noOfSections;
var gap;
var sectionColor;
var firstY;

//separate sections to follow:
//sessions
var sessionsStartY;
var sessionsEndY;

//activities values
var activitiesStartY;
var activitiesEndY;

//schools values
var schoolsStartY;
var schoolsEndY;

//data entry values
var daenStartY;
var daenEndY;

//general value setup
function generalSetUp() {

    noOfSections = 4;

    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 15;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight + 500;

    //section edge color and width
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;

    w = $("#canvas").width();
    h = $("#canvas").height();

    //gap between the sections should vary depending on screen size, 
    //one percent of the whole screen height should do
    //we want the numbers nice and round, hence parseInt
    gap = 15;
    sectionX = 5;
    firstY = 5;
    sectionColor = "rgba(240, 237, 238, 0.5)";

    //we want to fit all the sections on the screen without scrolling, so a bit of calculation is needed to get the
    //height of the section: total height minus top gap, minus bottom gap, minus all the gaps between the sections
    //divided by the total number of sections should give us the height of every section        
    sectionH = ((((h - firstY) - firstY) - (gap * (noOfSections-1))) / noOfSections);
    sectionH = parseInt(sectionH);
    //total available width minus left gap and right gap
    sectionW = ((w - sectionX) - sectionX);
    sectionW = parseInt(sectionW);

    titleFont = gap + 18 + "px Calibri";
    buttonFont = gap + 12 + "px Calibri";
}

//setup for values representing positions of each section
function sectionsSetUp() {
    //section values
    sessionsStartY = firstY;
    sessionsEndY = sessionsStartY + sectionH;

    //activities values
    activitiesStartY = sessionsEndY + gap;
    activitiesEndY = activitiesStartY + sectionH;

    //schools values
    schoolsStartY = activitiesEndY + gap;
    schoolsEndY = schoolsStartY + sectionH;

    //data entry values
    daenStartY = schoolsEndY + gap;
    daenEndY = daenStartY + sectionH;
}
```

And the average section drawing code looks like this:

```
//drawing each session: 
function createSessionsSection(sStartX, sStartY, sEndX, sEndY) {
    ctx.fillStyle=sectionColor;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(sStartX, sStartY, sEndX, sEndY);
    ctx.strokeRect(sStartX, sStartY, sEndX, sEndY);
}
```

What happens is it seems that the gap between the first and the second block is 15, the second gap is 0 and the third looks like -15, there is some overlapping going on with fillRects as well. I can't figure out what's causing this. 
Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Sorry, I'm mostly unfamiliar with JavaScript. What's a jsfiddle and why do I need it?

Comment: jsfiddle.net allows you to create small online webpages that you can use to replicate something happening on a web page.  So in your case you would copy your HTML and JS there so that people trying to help can view and play around with the code without requiring your actual HTML files.

Comment: Ah, right, didn't know about it. Here it is then: [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pat_a_dog/TfwK5/)

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't update the default framework to JQuery 1.8.3. But yeah. And it seems to produce the same result that I'm getting on my computer.

Comment: The content that goes in the HTML box is already in the body, so you do not need to paste the whole thing into the box.